VS Code : code cells are sometimes smaller or bigger than expected on jupyter notebook after cells navigation
I have this issue since I started working with Jupyter notebooks (~ May 2024), and also now (VS Code 1.96.2 and Jupyter extensions up to date).
It is intermittent, but when it happens, it is quite disturbing, although I found a workaround which fixes this until it happens again...
I think it happens when I have a notebook with a lot of cells (markdown and python cells), after I navigate fast on the notebook (cell down, cell down, cell up, last cell, cell down, cell up, first cell, etc...).
When the bug appears, the python code cell can be smaller or larger than expected.
My workaround to "refresh" the notebook is to show/hide the "outline" or the "explorer" panel on the side.
Here are some screenshots to give a better idea on the behavior I see.

case 1 : bigger code cell after some cells navigations

After workaround, it is fine :





case 2 : smaller code cell after some cells navigations

After workaround, it is fine :



On my notebook here, I have 123 cells.
I did not find similar issue in SO (maybe I did not search well).
A reboot of VS Code does not solve the issue.
How to fix it, please ?
I don't know anyone having this issue. If you reproduce it, it would be nice to leave a comment so that I know I am not alone :)
